# BreezeJS - Zza sample won't run

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to run the Zza sample. I've followed the instruction exactly. When I try and run: "node server" or "node server.js" I get:

C:\Users\RobbyV\Documents\Code\Breeze\Samples\Zza-Node-Mongo\Zza-Node-Mongo\server.js:9

```
app.configure(function(){
    ^
TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
   } has no method 'configure'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RobbyV\Documents\Code\Breeze\Samples\Zza-Node-Mongo\Zza-Node-Mongo\server.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, those instructions and the zip file that you downloaded were outdated. Discard them both.

I have since updated [**the web site page for the sample**](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza) with new download instructions and have updated the **readme.md** *within the sample* with instructions that work (having just now confirmed them).

Please try again and let me that it works for you now.

Comment: Thanks Ward! JSYK, the new readme has no line breaks. When I turn on wordwrap in notepad it's just one run on paragraph of text. It's a little hard to read. I'll give it another shot. Thanks again!

Comment: Huh? It's a markdown file in any case ... which is a pretty standard format these days (as in "right here on stackoverflow"). [**Github formats it nicely**](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/readme.md) if you'd rather read it there.